# Are these disjoint/dependent?

Tags: probability, solution-verification

> Given $P(A) = 0.7, P(B) = 0.6, P(A^c | B^c) = 0.25$, are:
>
> I) $A$ and $B$ disjoint?
>
> II) $A$ and $B$ dependent?

So, what I said:

> $I)$ Since $P(A) + P(B) = 1.3 > 1$ then $P(A \cap B) \neq \emptyset$, thus $A, B$ are non-disjoint.
>
> II) $P(A^c | B^c) = \frac{P(A^c \cap B^c)}{P(B^c)} = 0.25 \rightarrow P(A^c \cap B^c) = 0.1$. But $P(A^c \cap B^c) = 1 - [P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)] \rightarrow P(A \cap B) = 0.55$. From here we check: is $P(A \cap B) = P(A) \cdot P(B)? \rightarrow$ is $0.55 = 0.7 \cdot 0.6?$ NO! thus $A, B$ are dependent.

Is that correct or am I missing something? (new to probability)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct and so are your derivations, except that $P(A\cap B)=.4$ not 0.55.

$P(A^c\cap B^c)=.1=1-P(A\cup B)=1-[P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)] \rightarrow 0.9=.7+.6-P(A\cup B) \rightarrow P(A \cup B) = .7+.6-.9 = .4 \neq .7*.6 = .42$

Disjoint events have additive probabilities for their union and depnendent events are simply not independent, so you verified this witha a counterexample.

Comment: thank you for noticing the calculation mistake!